# du: cannot access '/tmp/swapnil-httpd-log-04072022-125152.tar

Tags: bash, shell

I am getting the following error in my script:

> du: cannot access '/tmp/swapnil-httpd-log-04072022-125152.tar

This I have use in script which get me a size of tar file:

```bash
tar_size=$(du -h /tmp/${name}-httpd-log-${timestamp}.tar | awk '{print $1}')
```

This is output of long list command on tmp:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 10240 Jul  4 12:51 swapnil-httpd-logs-04072022-125152.tar
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is maybe a typo error.
Fixed:

```
tar_size=$(du -h /tmp/${name}-httpd-**log[s]**-${timestamp}.tar | awk '{print $1}')
```

Or

```
tar_size=$(du -h /tmp/${name}-httpd-**logs**-${timestamp}.tar | awk '{print $1}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the value of either `name` or `timestamp` changes between when you create the file and when you check its size?

In these situations, you're probably better off creating a separate variable `filename` that you set only once, and then use each time you refer to the file.

Also, maybe consider using `ls -l` to get the file size?